How to concatenate the rating-bar markup of a star-rating component via a for-loop?
I have a rating number for 3 different products,
and I am trying to render a star svg based of their rating number.
For example product-A has rate 3, I want to render star img, 3 times.
The maximum star they can have is 5.
I wrote a code like this:
const ratingHandler = (productRate) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < productRate + 1; i++) {
    console.log(productRate);
    return `<img src="assets/star.svg" alt="rating-star" />`;
  }
};

Product rate shows the rating number correctly in my console.log, but the render in the loop doesn't render based of that number.

See Does return stop a loop?. But you should really describe what you're trying to do because it's not a return. Do you want to build up an array? A string? Append to the DOM?

i am trying to render img tags based of the number of rate each product has. If a product has rate 3, i want that img tag renders 3 times

Your maybe after something like -> const ratingHandler = (productRate) => new Array(productRate).fill('<img src="assets/star.svg" alt="rating-star" />').join('')

@Keith or maybe simpler as str.repeat(productRate)

@VLAZ  Old habits, :),  although that ones been available for a long time now..

The OP's actual problem goes much deeper. A star-rating should be seen as a component, an abstraction for a problem which gets implemented generically once. Thus, one aims for a reusable component which one can easily adapt by attribute-value changes and css changes. Its markup could be handled flexible, even though being provided semantically more correct than the OP's sequence of star images.

@PeterSeliger   Not really, you can certainly promote best practices and component re-usability, but the answers on SO are meant to be direct and simple.   Saying that, your answer is well presented, and I can see a lot of effort, and I can see other users stumbling onto SO might find it useful, and for that reason I'll be up-voting... :)

Your function ends as soon as it first hits the return. You need to build up the complete string before returning:
const ratingHandler = (productRate) => {
  let stars = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < productRate + 1; i++) {
    stars += `<img src="assets/star.svg" alt="rating-star" />`;
  }
  return stars;
};


amazing! thank you! this worked! I have one more question, for the rates that are less than 5, i want to add class  name ".inactiveStar" to that image tag, basically if the product has rating of 4, the img render 5 times but the last one has the class name .inactiveStar

@Afra that's an entirely different problem. I'd suggest you ask a new question about it instead of extending this one

@Afra maybe something like this - it uses unicode instead of images but you'll get the idea, just add your class to the else part.

@Andy it was very helpful, thank you!

Note the great comments of @VLAZ at the question:
const ratingHandler = productRate =>
  '<img src="assets/star.svg" alt="rating-star" />'.repeat(productRate+1)


For fun: maybe an alternative (no loop, use css background for images) way of creating the stars from a rating:
[Edits]

Added a dynamic star rating element to the snippet
Inspired by Peter Seliger's answer I created a (imho less convoluted) web component for 'ranking the stars'



const toBody = html => document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(`beforeend`, html);
document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);
  
[0, 4, 3, 1, 5, 2].forEach(v => toBody(rate(v)));

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
  `beforeend`,
  `<div class="rateMe" data-maxrate="10">
    ${rate(0, 10, true)}
    <div><button data-reset='1'>reset</button></div>
   </div> `
    
);

function rate(rating, n = 5) {
  return `<div data-nstars="${n}" data-rating="${rating}">
    ${`<span class="star active"></span>`.repeat(rating)}${
      `<span class="star inactive"></span>`.repeat(n-rating)}</div>`;
}

function handle(evt) {
  const rateElement = evt.target.closest(`.rateMe`);
  
  if (rateElement) {
    const maxRate = +rateElement.dataset.maxrate;
    const stars = rateElement.querySelectorAll(`.star`);
    rateElement.querySelector(`[data-rating]`).remove();
    const score = evt.target.dataset.reset ? 0 :
      [...stars].reduce((acc, s, i) => s === evt.target ? acc + i : acc, 1);
    return rateElement.insertAdjacentHTML(`afterBegin`, rate(score, maxRate));
  }
}
[data-rating]:before {
  content: attr(data-rating)'/'attr(data-nstars);
  color: green;
}

.star {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 3px;
}

.rateMe:before {
  content: 'Click to rate';
  display: block;
  margin: 1rem 0 0.2rem 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.rateMe div {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}

.inactive {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20height%3D%2250px%22%20width%3D%2250px%22%20version%3D%221.1%22%20id%3D%22Capa_1%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2047.94%2047.94%22%20xml%3Aspace%3D%22preserve%22%20fill%3D%22%23000000%22%20stroke%3D%22%23000000%22%20stroke-width%3D%220.62322%22%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22SVGRepo_bgCarrier%22%20stroke-width%3D%220%22%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22SVGRepo_tracerCarrier%22%20stroke-linecap%3D%22round%22%20stroke-linejoin%3D%22round%22%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22SVGRepo_iconCarrier%22%3E%20%3Cpath%20style%3D%22fill%3A%23FFFFFF%3B%22%20d%3D%22M26.285%2C2.486l5.407%2C10.956c0.376%2C0.762%2C1.103%2C1.29%2C1.944%2C1.412l12.091%2C1.757%20c2.118%2C0.308%2C2.963%2C2.91%2C1.431%2C4.403l-8.749%2C8.528c-0.608%2C0.593-0.886%2C1.448-0.742%2C2.285l2.065%2C12.042%20c0.362%2C2.109-1.852%2C3.717-3.746%2C2.722l-10.814-5.685c-0.752-0.395-1.651-0.395-2.403%2C0l-10.814%2C5.685%20c-1.894%2C0.996-4.108-0.613-3.746-2.722l2.065-12.042c0.144-0.837-0.134-1.692-0.742-2.285l-8.749-8.528%20c-1.532-1.494-0.687-4.096%2C1.431-4.403l12.091-1.757c0.841-0.122%2C1.568-0.65%2C1.944-1.412l5.407-10.956%20C22.602%2C0.567%2C25.338%2C0.567%2C26.285%2C2.486z%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E');
}

.active, .rateMe .star:hover {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20height%3D%2250px%22%20width%3D%2250px%22%20version%3D%221.1%22%20id%3D%22Capa_1%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2047.94%2047.94%22%20xml%3Aspace%3D%22preserve%22%20fill%3D%22%23000000%22%20stroke%3D%22%23000000%22%20stroke-width%3D%220.62322%22%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22SVGRepo_bgCarrier%22%20stroke-width%3D%220%22%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22SVGRepo_tracerCarrier%22%20stroke-linecap%3D%22round%22%20stroke-linejoin%3D%22round%22%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22SVGRepo_iconCarrier%22%3E%20%3Cpath%20style%3D%22fill%3A%23ED8A19%3B%22%20d%3D%22M26.285%2C2.486l5.407%2C10.956c0.376%2C0.762%2C1.103%2C1.29%2C1.944%2C1.412l12.091%2C1.757%20c2.118%2C0.308%2C2.963%2C2.91%2C1.431%2C4.403l-8.749%2C8.528c-0.608%2C0.593-0.886%2C1.448-0.742%2C2.285l2.065%2C12.042%20c0.362%2C2.109-1.852%2C3.717-3.746%2C2.722l-10.814-5.685c-0.752-0.395-1.651-0.395-2.403%2C0l-10.814%2C5.685%20c-1.894%2C0.996-4.108-0.613-3.746-2.722l2.065-12.042c0.144-0.837-0.134-1.692-0.742-2.285l-8.749-8.528%20c-1.532-1.494-0.687-4.096%2C1.431-4.403l12.091-1.757c0.841-0.122%2C1.568-0.65%2C1.944-1.412l5.407-10.956%20C22.602%2C0.567%2C25.338%2C0.567%2C26.285%2C2.486z%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E');
}




I too toke the chance of implementing an active Star-Rating component in order to demonstrate what I think the approach for a generic enough, accessible, customizable, maintainable, hence re-usable (web-)component might look like.

From my above comment ...

The OP's actual problem goes much deeper. A star-rating should be seen as a component, an abstraction for a problem which gets implemented generically once. Thus, one aims for a reusable component which one can easily adapt by attribute-value changes and css changes. Its markup could be handled flexible, even though being provided semantically more correct than the OP's sequence of star images.

The first step is to come up with a meaningful markup and some CSS ... no JavaScript involved yet.


[data-star-rating] {

  position: relative;
  /* display: inline-block; */
  display: block;
  /* margin: 0; */
  margin: 8px 0;

  > p,
  > span {
  
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 4px 0 0;

    &:after {
      content: ':'
    }
  }
  > output,
  > figcaption {

    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    color: transparent;

    &:after,
    &:before {

      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: -8px;

      content: '';
      
      font-size: 1.3em;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
      -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
    }

    &:after {
      color: white;
    }
    &:before {
      z-index: 1;
      color: gold;
    }

    &[data-max-amount="3"] {
      &:after {
        content: '★★★';
      }
    }
    &[data-max-amount="4"] {
      &:after {
        content: '★★★★';
      }
    }
    &[data-max-amount="5"] {
      &:after {
        content: '★★★★★';
      }
    }
    &[data-max-amount="6"] {
      &:after {
        content: '★★★★★★';
      }
    }
    &[data-max-amount="7"] {
      &:after {
        content: '★★★★★★★';
      }
    }

    &[data-amount="1"] {
      &:before {
        content: '★';
      }
    }
    &[data-amount="2"] {
      &:before {
        content: '★★';
      }
    }
    &[data-amount="3"] {
      &:before {
        content: '★★★';
      }
    }
    &[data-amount="4"] {
      &:before {
        content: '★★★★';
      }
    }
    &[data-amount="5"] {
      &:before {
        content: '★★★★★';
      }
    }
    &[data-amount="6"] {
      &:before {
        content: '★★★★★★';
      }
    }
    &[data-amount="7"] {
      &:before {
        content: '★★★★★★★';
      }
    }
  }
}
<figure data-star-rating>
  <p>Rating</p>
  <figcaption data-amount="4" data-max-amount="7" title="4 of 7 stars">
    4 of 7 stars
  </figcaption>
</figure>

<label data-star-rating>
  <span>Rating</span>
  <output data-amount="2" data-max-amount="5" title="2 of 5 stars">
    2 of 5 stars
  </output>
</label>

<figure data-star-rating>
  <p>Rating</p>
  <figcaption data-amount="1" data-max-amount="4" title="1 of 4 stars">
    1 of 4 stars
  </figcaption>
</figure>

<label data-star-rating>
  <span>Rating</span>
  <output data-amount="3" data-max-amount="3" title="3 of 3 stars">
    3 of 3 stars
  </output>
</label>

<figure data-star-rating>
  <p>Rating</p>
  <figcaption data-amount="5" data-max-amount="6" title="5 of 6 stars">
    5 of 6 stars
  </figcaption>
</figure>



The next iteration provides even better markup in terms of usage (the rating copy can be omited/shown), semantics and accessibility. The rules of the before shown CSS have been adapted according to this new HTML structure. On top sits the JavaScript which implements a star-rating web-component.
The implementation comes as autonomous custom element which has to inherit from the HTML-element base-class HTMLElement. This is due to Apple's lacking support of customized built-in elements which can inherit from standard HTML elements.
One can work around the semantic gap of not being able to use <figure is="star-rating"/> by utilizing an aria role like that <star-rating aria-role="figure" />.
The following example code features an additional script which allows the manipulation of each star-rating component in order to prove the component's concept and correct implementation.
Each star-rating component can be used by providing and or mutating/altering two custom data-* attribute values. It's as easy as that.


function parseDataKey(attrName) {
  return attrName
    .replace(/^data-/, '')
    .replace(/-(\p{Ll})/gu, (_, char) => char.toUpperCase());
}

function getApprovedAmountValue(initialData, dataKey, latestValue) {
  const initialValue = initialData[dataKey];

  latestValue = Number(latestValue);
  latestValue = Number.isFinite(latestValue) ? latestValue : initialValue;

  return String(
    approvedValue = (dataKey === 'maxAmount')
      && Math.max(3, Math.min(latestValue, initialValue))
      || Math.max(0, Math.min(latestValue, initialData['maxAmount'] ?? latestValue))
  );
}


class StarRating extends HTMLElement {
  static observedAttributes = ['data-amount', 'data-max-amount'];

  #initialData = {};
  #captionNode;

  constructor() {
    super();

    Object.assign(this.#initialData, {
      amount: null,
      maxAmount: null,
    })
    this.#captionNode = this.querySelector('[data-template-target]');
  }
  renderCaption() {
    const { dataset: { template, amount, maxAmount, } } = this;
    
    const ratingCopy = template
      .replace(/\${\samount\s\}/g, amount)
      .replace(/\${\smaxAmount\s\}/g, maxAmount);

    this.#captionNode.textContent = ratingCopy;
    this.title = ratingCopy;
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(attrName, recentValue, currentValue) {
    const dataKey = parseDataKey(attrName);

    if (recentValue === null) {
      this.#initialData[dataKey] = currentValue;
    }
    const approvedValue =
      getApprovedAmountValue(this.#initialData, dataKey, currentValue);

    if (approvedValue !== currentValue) {

      // set correct value and indirectly trigger method execution again .
      this.dataset[dataKey] = approvedValue;

    } else {

      // rendering of valid/sanitized value changes only.
      this.renderCaption();
    }    
  }
}
customElements.define("star-rating", StarRating);
star-rating/*, [is="star-rating"]*/ {

  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 12px 0;

  > figcaption:has(> [data-template-target]) {

    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1px 4px 0 0;

    > [data-template-target] {

      overflow: hidden;
      position: absolute;
      width: 0;
      
      &.visible {
        overflow: unset;
        position: unset;
        width: unset;
      }
    }
  }
  > [data-figure] {

    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: -1.3em;

    &:after,
    &:before {

      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;

      content: '';
      
      font-size: 1.3em;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
      -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
    }

    &:after {
      color: white;
    }
    &:before {
      z-index: 1;
      color: gold;
    }
  }

  &[data-max-amount="3"] {
    > [data-figure] {
      &:after {
        content: '★★★';
      }
    }
  }
  &[data-max-amount="4"] {
    > [data-figure] {
      &:after {
        content: '★★★★';
      }
    }
  }
  &[data-max-amount="5"] {
    > [data-figure] {
      &:after {
        content: '★★★★★';
      }
    }
  }
  &[data-max-amount="6"] {
    > [data-figure] {
      &:after {
        content: '★★★★★★';
      }
    }
  }
  &[data-max-amount="7"] {
    > [data-figure] {
      &:after {
        content: '★★★★★★★';
      }
    }
  }

  &[data-amount="1"] {
    > [data-figure] {
      &:before {
        content: '★';
      }
    }
  }
  &[data-amount="2"] {
    > [data-figure] {
      &:before {
        content: '★★';
      }
    }
  }
  &[data-amount="3"] {
    > [data-figure] {
      &:before {
        content: '★★★';
      }
    }
  }
  &[data-amount="4"] {
    > [data-figure] {
      &:before {
        content: '★★★★';
      }
    }
  }
  &[data-amount="5"] {
    > [data-figure] {
      &:before {
        content: '★★★★★';
      }
    }
  }
  &[data-amount="6"] {
    > [data-figure] {
      &:before {
        content: '★★★★★★';
      }
    }
  }
  &[data-amount="7"] {
    > [data-figure] {
      &:before {
        content: '★★★★★★★';
      }
    }
  }
}

fieldset { margin: 24px 0 0 0; label { margin: 0 8px 0 0; } }
<star-rating aria-role="figure"

  data-amount="1"
  data-max-amount="4"
  data-template="${ amount } of ${ maxAmount } stars">

  <figcaption>
    Rating:
    <span data-template-target class="visible">-- of -- stars</span> /
  </figcaption>

  <div data-figure></div>
</star-rating>


<star-rating aria-role="figure"

  data-amount="3"
  data-max-amount="3"
  data-template="${ amount } of ${ maxAmount } stars">

  <figcaption>
    Rating
    ... <span data-template-target class="visible">-- of -- stars</span> ...
  </figcaption>

  <div data-figure></div>
</star-rating>


<star-rating aria-role="figure"

  data-amount="5"
  data-max-amount="7"
  data-template="${ amount } of ${ maxAmount } stars">

  <figcaption>
    Rating:
    <span data-template-target>-- of -- stars</span>
  </figcaption>

  <div data-figure></div>
</star-rating>


<fieldset>
  <legend>Change Star Ratings</legend>

  <label>
    <span>1st Rating</span>
    <select data-idx="0">
      <option value="0">none</option>
      <option value="1" selected>★</option>
      <option value="2">★★</option>
      <option value="3">★★★</option>
      <option value="4">★★★★</option>
    </select>
  </label>

  <label>
    <span>2nd Rating</span>
    <select data-idx="1">
      <option value="0">none</option>
      <option value="1">★</option>
      <option value="2">★★</option>
      <option value="3" selected>★★★</option>
    </select>
  </label>

  <label>
    <span>3rd Rating</span>
    <select data-idx="2">
      <option value="0">none</option>
      <option value="1">★</option>
      <option value="2">★★</option>
      <option value="3">★★★</option>
      <option value="4">★★★★</option>
      <option value="5" selected>★★★★★</option>
      <option value="6">★★★★★★</option>
      <option value="7">★★★★★★★</option>
    </select>
  </label>
</fieldset>

<script>
document
  .querySelector('fieldset')
  .addEventListener('change', ({ target }) => {
    document
      .querySelectorAll('star-rating')
      .item(target.dataset.idx)
      .dataset.amount = target.value;  
  });
</script>



Edit ... particularly targeting @KooiInc's lates contributions, both his latest provided code-example in his own post and his comment on this post of mine ...

@KooiInc ... yep, the above example implements exclusively a passive star rating. And since it serves a "display only" purpose, one can keep the markup as semantically simple as a basic <figure/>. An active star-rating component should follow semantically a <fieldset/> which encloses a radio-group. – Peter Seliger

I have created a web component version implementing active rating. It uses a (non class syntax) custom web component module I created earlier. – KooiInc


And regarding @KooiInc's latest edit where he states ...

Inspired by Peter Seliger's answer I created a (imho less convoluted) web component for 'ranking the stars'.

... I too toke the chance for another code example where its implementation of an active Star-Rating Component is supposed to demonstrate what I mean by ...

a component's markup by default should be as semantically correct and accessible as possible.

a component's markup might even be interchangeable (as demonstrated with the "display only" passive star rating).

a components initial state, data and display wise, should be configurable by data-* attributes or/and by a component's custom attributes.

JavaScript gets used exclusively for managing a component's initialization, its UI interactions and its state changes (but not for managing its layout/design).

CSS has to cover every other UI related aspect of a component.


The next provided example shows 3 different tab-navigable Star-Rating components. And the 4th un-styled and JS-free radio-group enclosing fieldset proves that the markup of a component's underneath HTML structure can be written in a usable and re-usable way, even in the absence of styling and scripting, especially when one deals with (builds upon) form-controls.


function getValidatedInitialData(component) {

  const maxScoreUpperLimit = 13;
  const maxScoreLowerLimit = 3;

  const maxScoreDefault = 5;
  const scoreDefault = 0;

  let maxScore = Number(component.getAttribute('max-score') ?? maxScoreDefault);
  let score = Number(component.getAttribute('score') ?? scoreDefault);

  maxScore = Number.isFinite(maxScore)
    ? Math.max(maxScoreLowerLimit, Math.min(maxScoreUpperLimit, maxScore))
    : maxScoreDefault;

  return {
    maxScore,
    score: Number.isFinite(score)
      ? Math.max(0, Math.min(score, maxScore))
      : scoreDefault,
  };
}


function handleScoreItemStateChange(evt, nodes, state) {
  const { currentTarget: component, target: inputControl } = evt;

  const { scoreTarget, summaryTarget } = nodes;
  const { maxScore, summary } = state;

  // console.log('handleStateChange');

  const controlList = [
    ...scoreTarget.querySelectorAll(`[type="${ inputControl.type }"]`)
  ];
  const selectedIndex = controlList.indexOf(inputControl);

  state.selectedIndex = selectedIndex;
  state.score = selectedIndex + 1;

  inputControl.value = state.score;

  if (summaryTarget) {
    summaryTarget[summary.attrName] = summary.value = summary.literal

      .replace(/\${\sscore\s\}/g, state.score)
      .replace(/\${\smaxScore\s\}/g, maxScore);
  }
}

function renderSelector(component, nodes, state) {

  const { scoreTemplate, scoreTarget, summaryTarget } = nodes;
  const { maxScore, score, summary } = state;

  const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

  Array
    .from(
      { length: maxScore }, () => scoreTemplate.content.cloneNode(true),
    )
    .forEach((node, idx) => {
      const scoreValue = idx + 1;

      const labelTarget = node.querySelector('[data-label][data-literal]');
      const inputControl = node.querySelector('[type="radio"], [type="checkbox"]');

      if (labelTarget) {
        labelTarget.textContent = (labelTarget.dataset.literal ?? '')

          .replace(/\${\sscore\s\}/g, scoreValue)
          .replace(/\${\smaxScore\s\}/g, maxScore);

        Reflect.deleteProperty(labelTarget.dataset, 'literal');
      }
      inputControl.value = scoreValue;

      if (scoreValue === score) {

        state.selectedIndex = idx;
        state.score = scoreValue;

        inputControl.checked = true;
      }
      fragment.appendChild(node);
    });

  if (summaryTarget) {
    summaryTarget[summary.attrName] = summary.value = summary.literal

      .replace(/\${\sscore\s\}/g, state.score)
      .replace(/\${\smaxScore\s\}/g, maxScore);
  }
  Reflect.deleteProperty(nodes, 'scoreTemplate');
  scoreTemplate.remove();

  scoreTarget.appendChild(fragment);
}

function initializeSelector(component, nodes, state) {

  const { maxScore, score } = getValidatedInitialData(component);
  const { summaryTarget } = nodes;

  state.maxScore = maxScore;
  state.score = score;

  component.removeAttribute('max-score');
  component.removeAttribute('score');

  if (summaryTarget) {
    const { summary } = state;

    summary.attrName = ('value' in summaryTarget) && 'value' || 'textContent';
    summary.literal = summaryTarget.dataset.literal ?? '';

    Reflect.deleteProperty(summaryTarget.dataset, 'literal');
  }
  component.addEventListener('change', evt => handleScoreItemStateChange(evt, nodes, state));

  renderSelector(component, nodes, state);
}


class StarRatingSelector extends HTMLElement {

  #state = {
    maxScore: null,
    score: null,
    summary: {
      attrName: null,
      literal: null,
      value: null,
    },
    selectedIndex: -1,
  };
  #nodes = {};

  constructor() {
    super();

    Object.assign(this.#nodes, {
      scoreTemplate: this.querySelector('template[data-score-item]'),
      scoreTarget: this.querySelector('[data-score-target]'),
      summaryTarget: this.querySelector('[data-summary][data-literal]'),
    });
  }

  get selectedIndex() {
    return this.#state.selectedIndex;
  }
  get score() {
    return this.#state.score;
  }
  get maxScore() {
    return this.#state.maxScore;
  }
  get summary() {
    return this.#state.summary.value;
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    initializeSelector(this, this.#nodes, this.#state);
  }
}
customElements.define('star-rating-selector', StarRatingSelector);
star-rating-selector/*,
[is="star-rating-selector"]*/ {


  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 12px 0;

  &:has(> fieldset) {

    margin-top: 16px;
    padding: 0 0 4px 0;

    border: 1px solid black;
    border-top: none;
  } 
  > fieldset {

    position: relative;
    top: -.55em;
    margin: 0 0 -1.4em 0;
    border: none;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
  }


  > [data-summary] {

    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    &.visible {
      overflow: unset;
      width: unset;
      height: unset;
      margin: 0 0 6px 0;
      padding: 0 16px;
    }
  }
  [data-score-target] {

    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding: 0;

    [data-score-item] {

      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0 -2px;

      > [data-label] {

        overflow: hidden;
        float: left;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
      }
      > input {

        position: absolute;
        left: 8px;
        top: 10px;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
      }
      &::after {

        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        left: 0;
        top: 1px;
        padding: 1px 2px 0 2px;

        content: '★';

        font-size: 1.8em;
        line-height: 1em;

        color: white;
        -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
      }
      &:focus-within {
        &::after {
          -webkit-text-stroke: 3px blue;
        }          
      }
      &:hover {
        &::after {
          -webkit-text-stroke: 3px purple;
        }
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      &:has(:checked) {
        &::after {
          color: gold;
        }
      }
    }
    &:has(:checked) {

      [data-score-item] {
        &::after {
          color: gold;
        }
        &:has(:checked) ~ [data-score-item] {
          &::after {
            color: white;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    &:hover {

      [data-score-item] {
        &::after {
          color: yellow!important;
        }
        &:hover ~ [data-score-item] {
          &::after {
            color: white!important;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
details { padding: 4px 0 8px 0; }
summary { padding: 0 0 4px 0; }
<star-rating-selector aria-label="Star Rating Selector" role="group" max-score="4">
  <template data-score-item>
    <label data-score-item>

      <span data-label data-literal="Rate with ${ score } of ${ maxScore } stars.">
        rate -- of -- stars
      </span>
      <input type="radio" value="" name="out-of-four" />

    </label>
  </template>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Please provide a score</legend>
    <div data-score-target></div>
  </fieldset>

  <output data-summary data-literal="The current rating is ${ score } of ${ maxScore } stars." class="visible">
    -- of -- stars selected
  </output>
</star-rating-selector>


<star-rating-selector aria-label="Star Rating Selector" role="group" score="3" max-score="3">
  <template data-score-item>
    <label data-score-item>

      <span data-label data-literal="Rate with ${ score } of ${ maxScore } stars.">
        rate -- of -- stars
      </span>
      <input type="radio" value="" name="out-of-three" />

    </label>
  </template>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Please provide your rating</legend>
    <div data-score-target></div>
  </fieldset>

  <output data-summary data-literal="${ score } of ${ maxScore } stars selected." class="visible">
    -- of -- stars selected
  </output>
</star-rating-selector>


<star-rating-selector aria-label="Star Rating Selector" role="group" score="5" max-score="7">
  <template data-score-item>
    <label data-score-item>

      <span data-label data-literal="Rate with ${ score } of ${ maxScore } stars.">
        rate -- of -- stars
      </span>
      <input type="radio" value="" name="out-of-seven" />

    </label>
  </template>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Give some stars</legend>
    <div data-score-target></div>
  </fieldset>

  <output data-summary data-literal="${ score } of ${ maxScore } stars selected.">
    -- of -- stars selected
  </output>
</star-rating-selector>


<details>
  <summary>For Comparison Reason ...</summary>
  ... the CSS and JavaScript free base structure of any of the above "Star Rating" Components:
</details>


<fieldset aria-label="Star Rating Selector">
  <legend>Rate with ...</legend>

    <label>
      <span>
        1 of 5 stars
      </span>
      <input type="radio" value="" name="out-of-five" />
    </label>

    <label>
      <span>
        2 of 5 stars
      </span>
      <input type="radio" value="" name="out-of-five" />
    </label>

    <label>
      <span>
        3 of 5 stars
      </span>
      <input type="radio" value="" name="out-of-five" />
    </label>

    <label>
      <span>
        4 of 5 stars
      </span>
      <input type="radio" value="" name="out-of-five" checked />
    </label>

    <label>
      <span>
        5 of 5 stars
      </span>
      <input type="radio" value="" name="out-of-five" />
    </label>
</fieldset>




Nice idea, although a bit convoluted imho. A disadvantage here may that the user can not rate by just clicking one of the stars.

@KooiInc ... yep, the above example implements exclusively a passive star rating. And since it serves a "display only" purpose, one can keep the markup as semantically simple as a  basic <figure/>. An active star-rating component should follow semantically a <fieldset/> which encloses a radio-group.

I have created a web component version implementing active rating. It uses a (non class syntax) custom web component module I created earlier.

@KooiInc ... interesting, I kind'a like it. The advantages of the 'no class' approach, which abstracts the class-component bootstrap/boilerplate-code away, might come with forcing the development towards a function-based imperative style where one has to pass around all the needed references, data and events. Thus it prevents developers with lacking OO-experience from messing with code via bad design-choices and even worse implementations.

If you want to be the cool guy in class and nobody should understand your code, but it should still do its job, this is your go-to:
const ratingHandler = (productRate) => [undefined].concat(productRate ?? []).reduce((all) => all += '<img src="assets/star.svg" alt="rating-star" />', "");

Thank me later!
